# Why would Django (1.5.1) call Loader.load_template_source() 69 times?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-debug-toolbar

My problem originally manifested as a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error in a fairly run-of-the-mill `ListView`.  After digging around, I found a ton of cache hits originating in dbtemplates for every attempt I made to load the corresponding page.  This prompted me to write my own template loader, at which point it became apparent that Django is calling `load_template_source` exactly sixty-nine times every time the page is loaded.

Why would Django call `load_template_source` multiple times?

**visitor_index (db template)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{{ site.name }}</title>
    </head>
    <body id="home">
    <pre>
        Starting
        {% for video in videos %}
            {{ video.headline }}
        {% endfor %}
    </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns
from videos.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', VisitorIndex.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
import logging
from django.views.generic import ListView
from videos.models import Video

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class VisitorIndex(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'videos'
    template_name = 'visitor_index'

    def get_queryset(self):
        logger.debug('VisitorIndex.get_queryset()')
        return Video.on_site.filter(privacy_mode='PUB')
```

**loader.py**

```
import logging
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist
from django.template.loader import BaseLoader
from dbtemplates.models import Template

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Loader(BaseLoader):
    is_usable = True

    def load_template_source(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
        try:
            logger.debug('Loader.load_template_source(%s, %s)' % (template_name, template_dirs))
            template = Template.on_site.get(slug__exact=template_name).template_body
            logger.debug('Loaded template.')
            return template, template_name
        except Template.DoesNotExist:
            logger.debug('Template.DoesNotExist caught.')
            raise TemplateDoesNotExist, template_name
```

**models.py**

```
import logging
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.sites.managers import CurrentSiteManager
from django.db import models

logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')

class Template(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    template_body = models.TextField()
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)

    objects = models.Manager()
    on_site = CurrentSiteManager('site')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'dbtemplates.loader.Loader',
)
```

**app.log (updated with trace)**

```
2013-05-09 19:15:43,634 [DEBUG] dynamicsites.middleware: ENV_HOSTNAMES lookup subdomain=None domain=mydomain.com domain_unsplit=mydomain.com
2013-05-09 19:15:43,634 [DEBUG] dynamicsites.middleware: Checking database for domain=mydomain.com
2013-05-09 19:15:43,679 [DEBUG] dynamicsites.middleware: Using site id=2 domain=mydomain.com
2013-05-09 19:15:43,714 [DEBUG] videos.views: VisitorIndex.get_queryset()
2013-05-09 19:15:43,716 [DEBUG] django.template.response: SimpleTemplateResponse.rendered_content()
2013-05-09 19:15:43,717 [DEBUG] django.template.response: Start self.resolve_template()
2013-05-09 19:15:43,717 [DEBUG] django.template.response: SimpleTemplateResponse.resolve_template().  Found list or tuple.
2013-05-09 19:15:43,717 [DEBUG] django.template.response: Calling loader.select_template(template=['visitor_index', u'videos/video_list.html'])
2013-05-09 19:15:43,720 [DEBUG] dbtemplates.loader: Loader.load_template_source(visitor_index, None)
2013-05-09 19:15:43,722 [DEBUG] dbtemplates.loader:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 150, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 124, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 121, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 91, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 60, in resolve_template
    t = loader.select_template(template)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 188, in select_template
    return get_template(template_name)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 146, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 135, in find_template
    source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 43, in __call__
    return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 46, in load_template
    source, display_name = self.load_template_source(template_name, template_dirs)
  File "/home/wesley/howl/dbtemplates/loader.py", line 19, in load_template_source
    logger.debug(''.join(traceback.format_stack()))

2013-05-09 19:15:43,885 [DEBUG] dbtemplates.loader: Loaded template.
2013-05-09 19:15:43,886 [DEBUG] django.template.response: Done.
2013-05-09 19:15:43,887 [DEBUG] django.template.response: Done.  <django.template.base.Template object at 0x7fbdf8215050>
2013-05-09 19:15:43,887 [DEBUG] django.template.response: Start self.resolve_context()
2013-05-09 19:15:43,920 [DEBUG] django.template.response: Start template.render(context)
2013-05-09 19:15:43,920 [DEBUG] django.template.base: Template.render(context)
2013-05-09 19:15:43,920 [DEBUG] django.template.base:     context.render_context.push()
2013-05-09 19:15:43,920 [DEBUG] django.template.base:     Done.
2013-05-09 19:15:43,921 [DEBUG] django.template.base: Try self._render(context)
2013-05-09 19:15:43,932 [DEBUG] dbtemplates.loader: Loader.load_template_source(visitor_index, None)
2013-05-09 19:15:43,933 [DEBUG] dbtemplates.loader:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 150, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 124, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 121, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 97, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 146, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 65, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 148, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 90, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 775, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/wesley/howl/debug_toolbar/utils/tracking/db.py", line 134, in execute
    template_info = get_template_info(node.source)
  File "/home/wesley/howl/debug_toolbar/utils/__init__.py", line 80, in get_template_info
    template_source = origin.reload()
  File "/home/wesley/environments/howl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 80, in reload
    return self.loader(self.loadname, self.dirs)[0]
  File "/home/wesley/howl/dbtemplates/loader.py", line 19, in load_template_source
    logger.debug(''.join(traceback.format_stack()))

[...]
```

Comment: Could you show your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting? It looks like this is a configuration issue.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question to include `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **reproduced** your project **without** any **problem**.

The Loader is called only once without any recursion. I added also some simple necessary files: videos/models.py and also videos/admin.py, dbtemplates/admin.py in order to add two records Video and one record Template that loops over videos: `{% for video in videos %}...{% endfor %}`

I still can not believe that a recursion is possible in `Loader.load_template_source()`. More information is necessary.
Try to get a traceback from every call of your Loader by adding these two lines to it:

```
...
logger.debug('Loader.load_template_source......')
import traceback                                  # added
logger.debug(''.join(traceback.format_stack()))
...
```

(I am afraid that a loop or a recursion originated in other code that spawned many threads that all wait before the database operation until the currently running operation will be finished.)

---

**EDIT**: The **problem** is caused by **django-debug-toolbar**.

- The database cursor is wrapped by debug_toolbar monitoring code.
- It tries to introspect into the stack for the `template_info` of the template used by `render`.
- Template_info uses template reloading.
- That again needs the access to the database.

You can disable some parts of debug toolbar related to the database or to templates (not tested that it helps)  or disable it completely. Database operations are very good monitored by Django itself and the same done by debug toolbar is less important now.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try to recreate this, hynekcer.  I got the traceback as you requested and updated the app.log portion of my question with the results.

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you so much for looking into my question.  It's a huge help.

Incidentally, I tried disabling the SQL and template panels individually before uninstalling the app and middleware, but without effect.

Comment: Thanks hynekcer! I had a similar problem and this would have taken ages to figure out. In my case, removing the 'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel' panel from django-debug-toolbar fixed the issue.